# What is returned by jQuery append?

Tags: jquery

This is partly an honest question, partly a rant. Suppose I have html

```
<ol id="t"></ol>
```

and jQuery code

```
var x = $('#t').append('test');
var y = x.append('<ol>hello</ol>');
x.append('hello2');
y.append('hello3');
```

what should I expect to see?  I tried it here. http://jsfiddle.net/a7j5nw9z/ and it appears to me that the append function returns *this*. In other words x.append('foo') appears to usually return x.  I checked the jQuery documentation both [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/). The return value is undocumented. Can I safely assume that **all** jQuery functions will return *this* unless otherwise documented?  Is that documented somewhere? Just glancing through the jQuery docs, and **lots** of functions have undefined return values.

Comment: It always returns `this` to allow chaining.

Comment: jQuery methods always return the jQuery collection, unless they're specifically designed to return something else (like `.html()` or `.text()` called as getters). That is a basic feature of the library. It's not reasonable to expect that information to be repeated on every single page of the API.

Comment: @Juhana it actually **is** repeated, where it says "returns: jQuery"

Comment: w3schools is not documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Directly from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery):

> Most frequently, you will use the jQuery() function to create a jQuery
>   object. jQuery() can also be accessed by its familiar single-character
>   alias of $(), unless you have called jQuery.noConflict() to disable
>   this option. Many jQuery methods return the jQuery object itself, so
>   that method calls can be chained:
>
> **In API calls that return jQuery, the value returned will be the
>   original jQuery object unless otherwise documented by that API. API
>   methods such as .filter() or .not() modify their incoming set and thus
>   return a new jQuery object.**

emphasis mine; and in fact [`append()` returns `jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks very much. My fault, I did not read the doc closely enough.